# WCF Client code does not reflect WCF service data contract changes automatically

Tags: wcf

I originally have defined a data contract for testing purpose as

```
[DataContract]
public class CreditCard: ISensitive
{
   [DataMember]
   public string CardNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The Wcf client reads this contract properly and I can use client reference classes for manipulating CardNumber field. However, when I use .NET Entity framework to generate the data contract's actual implementation I do not see the changes reflected completely in the client reference classes.

```
[DataContract]
public partial class CreditCard: EntityObject
{
   // all Properties coming from database table
   [DataMember]
   public  string CardNumber { get; set; } 
   [DataMember]
   public string CardHolderName { get; set; } 
   [DataMember]
   public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
}

public partial class CreditCard: ISensitive
{
  // interface implementation and other methods
}
```

I am only able to manipulate CardNumber property, while other properties are not generated in the client code. I also do not see other entity types being generated on client code. Is there some versioning problem I am neglecting? Am I updating the service reference incorrectly? Why does the client code does not show DataContract classes generated by Entity Framework?

Comment: All very interesting. And your question is....?

Comment: Not entierly sure what your problem is... Are you trying to understand why you lose the changes??

Comment: sorry to bother you with text that made no sense. Here are the questions. Thanks

Comment: Why do you feel there is a versioning problem? There aren't a lot of ways to update the service reference, so you probably have that part right. As for the classes generated by EF, if this is a WCF service I believe it will only codegen those classes if they are exposed by a `ServiceOperation` (i.e., returned by or taken as a parameter to a method that WCF recognizes as a `ServiceOperation`).

Comment: you will have to update Service Reference at client side every time you update service contract or data contract at server side. If you want to bypass updating service reference you may try to use Channel Factory.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update your service definition on Client side, go to Solution Explorer. Under your client project, open 'Connected Services' and right-click on your Service Reference that connects to your buggy service. Select 'Update Service'. 
That should renew the service definition on your client side to match the host.